# Xamarin Port XCode to CSharp

Tags: c#, ios, xcode, xamarin

Im porting XCode code from https://github.com/bharath2020/UITableViewTricks into an Ios Xamarin Project.

I have already done all the translation from XCode to Csharp, things seems to work, minor alignment bug, but it's work.

But i still need help for a part that i don't understand.

In BBTableView.m We got a line with this

```
contentAlignment = eBBTableViewContentAlignmentLeft;
```

I see a line that seems to set this eBBTableViewContentAlignmentLeft params in BBTableView.h

If i understand this right i can define this in TableView.designer.cs 
but i can't figure out to do this in Csharp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three simple things to do.

1- Define your Enum

```
enum EBBTableViewContentAlignment{
     eBBTableViewContentAlignmentLeft,
     eBBTableViewContentAlignmentRight
};
```

2- Delaration

```
EBBTableViewContentAlignment contentAlignment;
```

3- Assignment

```
contentAlignment = EBBTableViewContentAlignment.eBBTableViewContentAlignmentLeft;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, do you know in which file i need to Define the enum, is it the designer.cs file or is it in my TableView class?

Comment: If the TableView class is the translated BBTableView class. You should add it in TableView class.

Comment: I will try with this. Thanks for the help